# AWS Personalize recommending majorly on recently activity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I am using AWS Personalize custom solution for user personalization. The recommendations I am receiving are heavily based on recent activity. Activities with the same level of frequency a day old are barely considered and older ones are completely ignored. What can I do to broaden this?

My solution configuration is the following:
Recipe: aws-user-personalization
Interaction data is around 75 million. Items are around 2 million. Users around 10 million.

`{ "performExploration": true, "algorithmHyperParameters": { "bptt": "16", "hidden_dimension": "70", "recency_mask": "false" }, "featureTransformationParameters": { "max_user_history_length_percentile": "0.95", "min_user_history_length_percentile": "0.05" } }`

My solution first had recency_mask enabled but even after disabling it, the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try increasing `bptt` and `hidden_dimension`, both of which consider more of a user's interaction history when ranking items when higher. The values you're using for these hyperparameters are below the [defaults](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/native-recipe-new-item-USER_PERSONALIZATION.html#bandit-hyperparameters) for this recipe. Since these hyperparameters are HPO-tunable, another option is to create a solution with HPO enabled (`performHPO=true`) and let Personalize determine the optimal values based on your data. Note that HPO will increase the training time (and therefore cost) but you can use the tuned parameter values from a solution trained with HPO enabled in a separate solution where you provide the values to use. This will keep retraining time and cost lower since you're retraining with the tuned values.

You indicated that you have `performExploration` set to `true` but didn't provide the value you're using for `explorationWeight` and `explorationItemAgeCutoff`. If you are using a high `explorationWeight`, cold items will be emphasized in recommendations which may be contributing to the results you are seeing.

Lastly, you have 2 million items in your dataset but Personalize currently limits the number of items included in the model to 750K (see [limits page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/limits.html#limits-table)). The service will select the items included in the model based on a balance of popularity and recency from the interactions. This could be a contributing factor.

Comment: I set explorationWeight = 0.1 and explorationItemAgeCutoff = 10. The values are low since I want recommendations to focus more on relevant results. I will be trying the model with a higher bptt and hidden_dimension.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion helped! I increased the bptt to 32 (the default) and the hidden dimensions to 200.